# Rxjava : Emit reduce value when switchmap happens

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

`reduce` operator emits value at the end of the observable (when completed).

I'm looking for a way to use `reduce` inside a `switchmap`. I **want** the `sum` of the infinite internal observable values when outer observable emits values or complete.

```java
@Test
public void emit_value_when_switchmap() throws InterruptedException {

    Observable.interval(0, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .switchMapMaybe(
                    l -> Observable.interval(0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .reduce(Long::sum)
                            .map(a -> a + ": Final")
            )
            .subscribe(e -> System.out.println(e));


    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

This diagram illustrates the wanted behavior :

```
//events: --------x-----1----2---1---x-----3--0--------x-1---1----|  
//result: ---------------------------4-----------------3----------2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the best way to do it, but it does the job for now, until someone comes up with a fancier method to resolve your use-case.

Please have a look at my test, I think it resolves your question:

Environment: (gradle -- groovy)

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8"
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0"
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.0"
testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0"
```

Test
3 emits are being made from the source observable. Each time a new value is emitted, the inner observable is subscribed to. When a new value is emitted, the inner observable completes and pushes the value downstream. Then the newly emitted value will be processed by subscribing to a new inner-stream.

```
  @Test
  public void takeWhileReduce() {
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    PublishSubject<Integer> source = PublishSubject.create();

    Observable<Long> publish = source.publish(
        multicast -> {
          return multicast.flatMap(
              o -> {
                return Observable.interval(0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler) //
                    .takeUntil(multicast)
                    .reduce(Long::sum)
                    .toObservable();
              },
              1);
        });

    TestObserver<Long> test = publish.test();

    source.onNext(42);

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // action - push next value - flatMapped value will complete and push value
    source.onNext(42);
    // assert - values emitted: 0,1,2,3
    test.assertValuesOnly(6L);

    // next value is flatMapped
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // action - push next value - flatMapped value will complete and push value
    source.onNext(42);

    // assert - values emitted: 0,1,2
    test.assertValuesOnly(6L, 3L);

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // action - push next value - flatMapped value will complete and push value
    source.onNext(42);

    // assert - values emitted: 0,1
    test.assertValuesOnly(6L, 3L, 1L);
  }
```

Comment: Really, great answer, thank you ... can you tell me why `maxConcurrency` is `1`?

Comment: I have to look into the implementation, but as I understand it, it makes sure, that at most one inner-stream is subscribed to. Therefore the inner-stream must complete or terminate, that a new value is flatMapped into. As a result, it might produce a memory-leak, because if the inner-stream never completes, all values from the source are being cached (>> maxConcurrency – the maximum number of ObservableSources that may be subscribed to concurrently). But I have to check, whether my assumption is true for "memory-leak".

Comment: Ok thank you again ... I've replaced it by `flatMapMaybe`. Now I've to process the last item differently from the others and I don't want the complete event to generate me the last event. Here's a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64682805/rxjava-takeuntil-skip-complete-event if you can help me again

Comment: It is not a good idea to use flatMapMaybe, because it does not support maxConcurrency. The default maxConcurrency is 128, if not set to a different value. When maxConcurrency is not set, it might happen, that multiple streams subscribed at once and therefore emitted values could be out of order (flatMap = merge + map). In order to make sure, that only one inner stream is subscribed at a time, you should use my example. If you do not care about it, or do not emit from different threads, you could just use your solution.