# Rxjava : takeUntil skip complete event

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

> **[TakeUntil](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html)**
> discard any items emitted by an Observable after a second Observable emits an item or terminates

Is there a way to skip the `complete` event when using `takeUntil` operator ?

```java
Observable<Long> publish = source.publish(
        multicast -> multicast.flatMapMaybe(
                o -> Observable.interval(0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
                        .takeUntil(multicast)
                        .reduce(Long::sum)
        )
);
```

This diagram illustrates the generated result for the code above :

```
//events: --------x-----1----2---1---x-----3--0--------x-1---1----|  
//result: ---------------------------4-----------------3----------2
```

What I want is to process `4` and `3` events differently from the last event `2` which is generated from the `complete` event of the `source`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a followup of [64676462](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676462/rxjava-emit-reduce-value-when-switchmap-happens)

My result is not pretty, but I think it does work. Your use-case is not that easy to resolve, because you do not know that a emitted value is "last", becase it is a stream. You can not emit the "last" value and know, that it is the last, because the emit and the onComplete are two atomar operations. You would need to delay emitting the "last" value and wait for the onComplete event, in order to be sure, that the "last" value is really the last value.

You could also cheat a little bit, like I did here:

NOTE: a flatMap completes, when the source observable and the inner subscribed observable complete. Therefore we have to make sure, that the inner stream also completes, when the source completes. This is achieved by using another #takeUntil, which listens to the onComplete-event from the source via #materialize. The #takeUntil after reduce makes sure, that the reduce value is not emitted downstream. At last #switchIfEmpty will convert the onComplete event from the "last" value to another value, because the observable did not emit any values.

NOTE: assumption is, that all values emit sync from one thread.

```
@Test
public void takeWhileReduce() {
    TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    PublishSubject<Integer> source = PublishSubject.create();

    Observable<Long> publish = source.publish(
            multicast -> {
                return multicast.flatMap(
                        o -> {
                            return Observable.interval(0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler) //
                                    .takeUntil(multicast)
                                    .reduce(Long::sum)
                                    .toObservable()
                                    // make sure, that the inner stream completes, when the outer stream completes.
                                    // takeUntil must be after reduce, because takeUntil will close the stream and therefore reduce
                                    // will push its value to the subscriber.
                                    .takeUntil(multicast.materialize().filter(Notification::isOnComplete))
                                    // when the upstream is closed, switch over to a fallback observable.
                                    // if you want special handling for the "LAST" value, just provide another fallback observable.
                                    .switchIfEmpty(Observable.just(Long.MAX_VALUE));
                        },
                        1);
            });

    TestObserver<Long> test = publish.test();

    source.onNext(42);

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // action - push next value - flatMapped value will complete and push value
    source.onNext(42);
    // assert - values emitted: 0,1,2,3
    test.assertValuesOnly(6L);

    // next value is flatMapped
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // action - push next value - flatMapped value will complete and push value
    source.onNext(42);

    // assert - values emitted: 0,1,2
    test.assertValuesOnly(6L, 3L);

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // action - push next value - flatMapped value will complete and push value
    source.onNext(42);

    // assert - values emitted: 0,1
    test.assertValuesOnly(6L, 3L, 1L);

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // action - outer-stream completes
    source.onComplete();

    test.assertComplete().assertValues(6L, 3L, 1L, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: thanks again, But I can't understand :( ... why two `takeUntil` and why should I use `switchIfEmpty` (this is a simplifed exemple of my code, I use immutable objects rather than `long`) ? I know this is a complicated use case :)

Comment: I probably do not get, what you are trying to do. Do you want to calculate the "last" value 2 and process it later differently or do you want to discard the reduce of the "last" value completely and and emit something differently?

Comment: I want to discard the reduce of le last value ... yeh I think it's not possible I need something else to filter on

Comment: If you want to not process the result of the last emitted "reduce", then my solution will suffice. I will update the answer in order to explain in detail what actually happens.